# Custom directive similar to v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I looking for something like custom `v-if` directive.
Let guess that we have something like this:

```
<button v-permission="admin" @click='Save'>
```

where `v-permission` is custom `vue` directive that looks:

```
Vue.directive('permission', {
    // send request that check if user has permission, if not don't render component
});
```

I have API that returns `true` or `false` for current user permission.
Is is possible? or maybe I just thinking wrong.

PS. I need to reuse this directive in multiple components, simply `v-if` and `getPermission` per component is not enough.

Comment: [There are actually some good articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=v-permission+vue) about exactly this in these links. My personal opinion is that it's unnecessary, but should you choose otherwise, there you go.

Comment: It's probably best that you abstract this to the router and then pass that information directly into the loaded component or store and consume it in locally.